# jQuery: Applying div ID to .load ID

Tags: jquery

Please bare with my lack of knowledge in the field. I'm trying to make a script that will target the first-child, grab its ID, and apply it to the name of the div that it will load + _description.

I have about 100 products, and adding a line of code for each isn't of much help.

eg.
Trying to make this automated:

```
<div class='descr'>
<div id='productName'>
<div id='productName_description>This is what needs to be inserted</div>
</div>
</div>



$('#productName').load('https://www.website.com/page.html #productName_description');
```

I got as far as:

```
$('descr:first-child').load('https://www.website.com/page.html ??????');
```

I can't figure out how to abstract 'descr:first-child's ID and apply it '+ _description' to the div that load is calling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide us more code/information, but with what I understood, try something like that :

```
// Javascript (document.ready)

$('.descr').each(function(){
  var productContainer=$(this).children().attr('id')+'_description';
  $('#'+productContainer).load('https://www.website.com/page.html #'+productContainer);

});
```

**Edit regarding your update**

Try the following :

```
var productContainer=$('.descr:first-child').attr('id')+'_description';
$('#'+productContainer).load('https://www.website.com/page.html #'+productContainer);
```

Comment: Just updated the question to contain more details as to what I'm trying to get to.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand your question, you want this:

```
$('#productName_description').load('https://www.website.com/page.html ??????');
```

Also your line:

```
<div id='productName_description>
```

should be with `'` at the end of the id:

```
<div id='productName_description'>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique so please specify your question further if you run into problems selecting multiple elements/descriptions. Is not 100% clear what you want at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I understood, I think this might solve your problem.

Lets say your 100's products listed below:

```
<div class='descr'>
    <div id='ipod'>
        iPod
    </div>
    <div id='iphone'>
        iPhone
    </div>
    <div id='ipad'>
        iPad
    </div>
</div>​
```

And you hit some ajax url which should return some results (HTML) and extract the DOM fragment (productname_description) out of it based on your productname and load it into your product div.

```
$(function () {
    $('div.descr').children().each (function () {
    var productDescriptionDOM = '#' + $(this).attr('id') + '_description';
       $(this).load('http://jsfiddle.net/echo/html/ '+productDescriptionDOM);
    });    
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vBxWs/

Please note that the demo will not load the products' descriptions because the request does not return any response. Can not use cross-domain url in the demo as it is not supported.

Comment: Don't you think that you copied and pasted my answer ??

Comment: @Valky: It looks similar but I did not see your answer when I posted mine.

Comment: No matter, just put me a +1 so ;-)

Comment: Haha!! Let me do it (I do not mind even you've down voted me)

Comment: Thanks ! Just edit your answer, then I could do a +1 to you too :-)

Comment: @Valky : My answer is a little different than yours. Your solution considers each product wrapped by div.descr whereas my solution considers multiple products wrapped by single div.descr. As both the solutions are in jQuery so the syntax and methods used will always be the same.

Comment: Yes, but mine is based on the question :-)
Because, we don't really know if he gonna use multiple or alone div... Regarding to his HTML my solution is good, regarding for optimization, yours is better.

Comment: I was telling you to edit your answer (not modify it), because without this I can't add an up vote to your answer :-)